# Code Coverage Issue with Spring ResultSetExtractor

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockito, cobertura

Code coverage of Resultsetextractor anonymous class is not covered.
There is no excecption at run time , it is running fine.

We have mocked the jdbcTemplate using below sample code.

**Mockito.when(mainTemplate.query(QUERY, new HashMap(),rs)).thenReturn(new Object());**

Below Code (start with @Override annotation - extractData() method)  is not covered after execution.

return mainTemplate.query(Query, paramMap, new ResultSetExtractor>() {

```
        **@Override
        public Map<String, Object> extractData(ResultSet resultSet)
                throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
            Map<String, Object> keyMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                keyMap.put("key1",
                        resultSet.getString("data1"));
                keyMap.put("key2", resultSet.getString("data2"));
            }
            return keyMap;
        }**
    });
```

Please help.

```
Please check sample code for your information.

    **return jdbcTemplatre.query(Query, paramMap, new ResultSetExtractor<byte[]>() {
                @Override
                public byte[] extractData(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException,
                        DataAccessException {
                    byte[] data = null;
                    while (resultSet.next()) {
                        signature = resultSet.getBytes("data");
                    }
                    return data;
                }
            });**


    Mockito.when(mainTemplate.query(Query, new HashMap<String,Object>(),rs)).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>(){
                 @Override
                    public byte[] answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
                        ResultSetExtractor resultSetExtractor = invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(2,ResultSetExtractor.class);
                        return (byte[]) resultSetExtractor.extractData(resSet);
                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

The `ResultSetExtractor` code is not covered because it is never executed. And it is not executed because the `mainTemplate.query` call is mocked thus the `ResultSetExtractor` callback is never triggered.
You could triggered it while still using the mock by using Mockitos [thenAnswer](http://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.7.19/org/mockito/stubbing/Answer.html)

```
Mockito.when(mainTemplate.query(QUERY, new HashMap(),rs)).thenAnswer(new Answer<Object>() {
    @Override
    public String answer(InvocationOnMock invocationOnMock) throws Throwable {
        ResultSetExtractor resultSetExtractor = invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(2, ResultSetExtractor.class);
        resultSetExtractor.extractData(...);
        return new Object();
    }
});
```

Or with java 8

```
Mockito.when(mainTemplate.query(QUERY, new HashMap(),rs)).thenAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
    ResultSetExtractor resultSetExtractor = invocationOnMock.getArgumentAt(2, ResultSetExtractor.class);
    resultSetExtractor.extractData(...);
    return new Object();
});
```

But testing this way you would have to create a `ResultSet` yourself.

But generally speaking: this way of calling `resultSetExtractor.extractData` in the mock might cause problems because it is making assumptions about how the `jdbcTemplate.query` method handles the ResultSetExtractor internally. But that behaviour might change and then your test does not represent anymore what actually happens in production.

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. We have applied same logic but still same issue - line is not covered by Cobertura when we run test.

Comment: Shared sample code attached with above question , please have a look and suggest. Looking forward to your great support and cooperation

Comment: Sorry to hear that it did not solve the issue. I have to admit that i have currently no idea what might cause the problem.